# Problem in checking the type of the variable

Tags: python, list, class, variables, types

I have a list of dictionary :

> list=[{'step' : '1' , 'name' : 'A'}]

and I want to check type of the value of step key in a if condition.

I have tried :

```
if (x=isinstance(list[0]['step'],str)) :
```

But i got this error :

> TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Also I tried :

```
list[0]['step'].__class__ == str
```

but got an error as well.
What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Don't use `list` and `str` as names for your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `list` as a variable name, because it's already used by python for datatype list. If you change `list` to `mylist`, the check works.

```
In [1]: mylist=[{'step' : '1' , 'name' : 'A'}]

In [2]: mylist 
Out[2]: [{'name': 'A', 'step': '1'}]

In [3]: if isinstance(mylist[0]["step"], str):
   ...:     print(True)
   ...:     
True
```